# Foreign key stays empty after persisting entity with OneToMany association

Tags: doctrine-orm, annotations, associations

Given are the following two entity classes

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table()
 */
class Tree
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\Column(type="guid")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
     * @var string
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Apple", mappedBy="tree", cascade={"persist"})
     * @var Collection
     */
    private $apples;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->setApples(new ArrayCollection());
    }

    public function toArray(): array
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->getId(),
        ];
    }

    public function getId(): string
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId(string $id): void
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function getApples(): Collection
    {
        return $this->apples;
    }

    public function setApples(Collection $apples): void
    {
        $this->apples = $apples;
    }
}
```

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table()
 */
class Apple
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\Column(type="guid")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
     * @var string
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Tree", inversedBy="apples")
     * @var Tree
     */
    private $tree;

    public function toArray(): array
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->getId(),
        ];
    }

    public function getId(): string
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId(string $id): void
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function getTree(): Tree
    {
        return $this->tree;
    }

    public function setTree(Tree $tree): void
    {
        $this->tree = $tree;
    }
}
```

The database schema looks good except for `apple.tree_id` being nullable. Is that already an issue in this case?

I'm persisting entries like the following:

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types = 1);

namespace App\Service;

use App\Entity\Apple;
use App\Entity\Tree;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class Gardener
{
    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function plantTree(): array
    {
        $entityManager = $this->entityManager;
        $tree          = new Tree();

        $blueApple = new Apple();
        $redApple  = new Apple();
        $tree->getApples()->add($blueApple);
        $tree->getApples()->add($redApple);

        $entityManager->persist($tree);
        $entityManager->flush();

        return (array) $tree;
    }
}
```

When executing the persist and flush there are no errors or warnings. A tree an two apple entries are beingt store, the `apple.tree_id` is however always null.

It seems like I have a misconfiguration on the entity classes, but am not sure what it is. I also tried adding a `JoinColumn` annotation `@ORM\JoinColumn(name="tree_id", referencedColumnName="id")`, but it did not make any difference.

What changes do I need to make, to have `appe.tree_id` being set properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your missing the adder & remover functions on the `*ToMany` side.

If your using Symfony >4 then replace `setApples` function with:

```
public function addApple(Apple $apple): Tree
{
    $this->apples->add($apple);

    return $this;
}

public function removeApple(Apple $apple): Tree
{
    $this->apples->removeElement($apple);

    return $this;
}
```

If you're using Zend Framework 3, then replace `setApples` function with:

```
public function addApples(array $apples): Tree
{
    foreach ($apples as $apple) {
        if (! $this->apples->contains($apple) {
            $this->apples->add($apple)
            $apple->setTree($this);
        }
    }
    return $this;
}

public function removeApples(array $apples): Tree
{
    foreach ($apples as $apple) {
        if($this->apples->contains($apple) {
            $this->apples->remove($apple);
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Have a read of the [Working with Association](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-associations.html#association-management-methods) docs, which show examples and explain how to update back 'n' forth.